# projective varieties and morphisms from infinitesimals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(A, m)$ be a local ring and $X$ a projective $A$-scheme. Let $f \in m$. If there is a $\operatorname{Spec} A$ morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A/(f) \rightarrow X$, then for any $n$ there is a $\operatorname{Spec} A$ morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A/(f^n) \rightarrow X$. Is this true? I think it is only supposed to be true if $X$ is smooth and $(A, (f))$ is a henselian pair, but I don't understand where the error is in the proof below.

Since $X$ is projective, it is locally defined by homogeneous polynomials over $A$. So morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A/(f) \rightarrow X$ induces $A$-homomorphism $A[T_1, \dots, T_n]/I \rightarrow A/(f),$ where $I=(P_1, \dots, P_m)$, and $P_j$ are homogeneous. Let $a_i \in A$ such that $T_i \mapsto a_i  \ \mathrm{mod} (f).$ Then, we can define $A[T_1, \dots, T_n]/I \rightarrow A/(f^n), T_i \rightarrow f^{n-1} a_i \ \mathrm{mod} (f^n),$ and hence have a $\operatorname{Spec} A$ morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A/(f^n) \rightarrow X$. Why is this not correct?

Is there hope of this statement being true under hypotheses weaker than smoothness?

Comment: I believe that one wants such map $B \to A/(f^n)$ commutes with the given map $B \to A/(f)$ under the natural surjective map $A/(f^n) \to A/(f)$. The defined map maps any product of two variables to 0.

Comment: But why do we want the maps to commute? I don't really ask or need that.